# Places search box zooming too much

Tags: google-maps

I have places a google places searchbox on my map and want to set bounds automatically returned by google.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=FR

However if i type 'London, United Kingdom', The result is zooming too much. I want the same result bounds which I get while typing the same on maps.google.co.uk.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: same as the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=FR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a places-Autocomplete instead of a searchbox and set the bounds of the map to the [**viewport**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry) returned for the particular place.

Comment: Great... worked like a charm.. thank you so much you saved my day.